# GPU passthrough with vmware

Tags: ubuntu, opencl, vmware, gpu

I'm stuck since 2 days trying to have my Graphic card working in a Vmware host.

Specifications:

- Vvmware ESXi 5.0.0 running on Windows
- Ubuntu 10.04 running on host
- Graphic card: AMD Radeon 6900 Series

Useful output :

```
#lspci -v
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc Cayman PRO [AMD Radeon 6900 Series]
Subsystem: PC Partner Limited Device 186b
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b2420000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
I/O ports at 4400 [size=256]
Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [a0] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask- 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information <?>
Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting <?>
Kernel driver in use: fglrx_pci
Kernel modules: fglrx
```

I'm starting my ubuntu in text mode.
I try to have OpenCL running in my VM. I tried a lot of various tutorials with ati-stream and so on and nothing works.
Then I followed [This](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=40213&page=2)

After I did it I got this message at startup:

```
    dmesg|grep radeon
    [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.6 root=UUID=1b5bd568-6b7f-41c0-be1c-d69ae4f7e438 ro text splash video=radeon:modeset=1

[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.6 root=UUID=1b5bd568-6b7f-41c0-be1c-d69ae4f7e438 ro text splash video=radeon:modeset=1
[    2.670567] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    2.671623] radeon 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.672877] radeon 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 18 (level, low) -> IRQ 18
[    2.679567] radeon 0000:03:00.0: BAR 6: can't assign [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x0] (bogus alignment)
[    2.680456] radeon 0000:03:00.0: BAR 6: can't assign [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x0] (bogus alignment)
[    2.681299] [drm:radeon_get_bios] *ERROR* Unable to locate a BIOS ROM
[    2.682179] radeon 0000:03:00.0: Fatal error during GPU init
[    2.683291] [drm] radeon: finishing device.
[    2.693101] radeon 0000:03:00.0: PCI INT A disabled
[    2.696322] radeon: probe of 0000:03:00.0 failed with error -22
```

So, I know that the passthrough is working since I can see my graphic card in my host but I can't make it work right.

Can anyone help me? Ask me if you need more information!

Comment: I feel this belongs on SuperUser - this isn't really about programming but about troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I think the AMD OpenCL drivers (and catalyst) are somehow tied to the X11 packages.
Try starting a Xorg server inside your VMWare and write a simple device query in OpenCL to see if you can access the card. If xorg is not installed at all, that might be a problem too.
Also can you see the card using `aticonfig --lsa` as root?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will test that tomorrow.

After I installed the driver and run startx it uses the graphic card output, meaning the real screen connected to the ATI.

I will give you the output tomorrow. Good evening